# selected music not playing from iPhone music library

Tags: iphone, mpmusicplayercontroller

I have created an iPhone application. Using this application, I can able to record my voice and able to play that recorded file. But if I select a music file from library, it is not playing.

```
// sample code that I have used in my application

self.player = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *songNamePredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue: self.songName forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
MPMediaQuery *mySongQuery = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];
[mySongQuery addFilterPredicate: songNamePredicate];
[player setQueueWithQuery:mySongQuery];
[player play];
```

Please help me to resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *songNamePredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue: self.songName forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
```

to

```
MPMediaPropertyPredicate *songNamePredicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:self.songName forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonContains];
```

also what is the value of the query result